# Angular, get dynamic value of textbox to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

i fetch from json and set the value to my angular ionic app. my textbox holds the value. but im unable to get the textbox value to controller. this is how i have done it

**controller.js**

```
$http.post("http://www.fooget.com/mydetails.php).success(function(details){
$scope.mydetails= details;
});
```

and i set the value to my html page

```
<form>
<div  ng-repeat="data in details|limitTo:1">
<p>{{data.f_name}}</p> <!--displays the value-->
<input type="text" ng-model="v.name" value="{{data.f_name}}"/> <!--empty values-->
<input type="text" ng-model="v.id" value="{{data.id}}"/> <!--empty values-->
<button ng-click="push(v)">
</form>
```

on form click i dont get the textbox values to my controller, im trying to get the vaules to the controller. it doesnt appear

```
$scope.push= function (v) { 
var push_name = v.name; // empty values
var push_id = v.id; // empty values
}
```

Comment: have you mentioned ng-controller to right one?

Comment: yes both comes under one controller

Comment: @Naz141 You have mentioned `details` in ng-repeat. Hope it should be `mydetails` as you have defined `$scope.mydetails` in your controller

Comment: that is my mistake in typing, anyways i still face the problem in not getting the value to the textboxes

Answer (score 1):

Also in your HTML:

```
<div  ng-repeat="data in details|limitTo:1">
```

It should be

```
<div  ng-repeat="data in mydetails|limitTo:1">
```

as you have `$scope.mydetails` and not `details`

The real problem is in initializing the values for `ng-model`:

As you're just setting the `value` attribute in input text, it's not assigned to the `ng-model`. Use `ng-init` directive to set it in the view.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="v.name" ng-init="v.name=data.f_name"/> 
<input type="text" ng-model="v.id"  ng-init="v.name=data.id"/>
```

This will work for you.

Comment: this never works, 
`<input type="text" ng-model="v.name" ng-init="v.name=data.f_name"/> `
this input does not view the value or cannot get the value to controller